# How do you combine columns in SQL to create a datetime format?

Tags: sql, datetime

Currently, I am working with a database that has the following columns:

```
  Date          Time of Day
2020-06-01          1230
2020-06-01          1231
2020-06-01          1232
2020-06-01          1233
2020-06-01          1234
```

I am looking to have a query that returns a single query in datetime format as such:

```
       Datetime
2020-06-01 12:30:00.000
2020-06-01 12:31:00.000
2020-06-01 12:32:00.000
2020-06-01 12:33:00.000
2020-06-01 12:34:00.000
```

How would this be done in SQL

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Have you even read the documentation of your dbms on how you do that???

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you could write this as:

```
select date + floor(time / 100) * interval '1 hour' + mod(tim, 100) * interval '1 minute'
```

`date`/`datetime` functions differ significantly among databases, though.  All should support the idea, but the syntax differs.